# C# webbrowser navite to local file. Spaces in path

Tags: c#, uri, webbrowser-control

I'm using webbrowser control in C# application to display different local files, not necessarily web pages but also images and pdf.files.

I noticed that it works:

```
string path = "C:\MyDirectory\file.png";   
webBrowser1.Navigate(path,false);
```

but if there are spaces in directories names it fails:

```
string path = "C:\My Directory\file.png";   
webBrowser1.Navigate(path,false);
```

What is the trick to display such files correctly in webbrowser control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefix your string with @ for local and UNC paths.

```
string localpath = @"drive:\Some Folder\file with spaces.extension";
string uncPath = @"\\network machine\Resources\Some Resource.extension";
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi sorry I can't post a comment without more rep but if I understand correctly, the WebBrowser class is basically like a IE wrapper, and so URLs with spaces or special characters in need to be encoded like so:

```
string path = System.Uri.EscapeDataString(url)
```

So that it will replace spaces with %20 etc and WebBrowser should know where to go.

Checkout the docs for [EscapeDataString](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work fo me. I get "Value does not fall within the expected range" error.